# Internal Storage: Why is getFilesDir() giving me the wrong folder?

Tags: java, android, firebase-storage

I am developing an android app. I want to download files from Firebase Storage to the internal storage and be able to play them afterwards (audio files). I use getFilesDir() to achieve that.

Everything works fine on the emulator. My audio directory is located at

> /data/user/0/com.package.name/files/audio/

The problem occurs on some **Huawei devices** (phone and tablet) with **Android API 28.**

I get the error, that my audio folder can't be found at the location mentioned above and with the device file explorer I can clearly see that there is no **data/user/** folder but instead the system still uses the old **/data/data/com.package.name/** directories.

**So my question is:**

does someone have an idea why **getFilesDir()** is not giving me the right path and how I could fix this without hardcoding the path.

Here is some code, I have also tried to **call exists()** on the root folder, with no success.

```java
    String filename = document.getId() + ".m4a";
    String rootPath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    File root = new File(rootPath);

//not working
    if(!root.exists()){
        rootPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + File.separator + "files"
                + File.separator + "voice" + File.separator;
    }
//

    String folderPath = rootPath + File.separator + "voice" + File.separator;
    File subFolder = new File(folderPath);

    if(!subFolder.exists()){
        subFolder.mkdir();
    }

    final File localFile = new File(subFolder, filename);
    final StorageReference voiceRef = uploadsRef.child("voice").child(filename);
    voiceRef.getFile(localFile);
```

Comment: The reason `getFilesDir()` exists is because the absolute path can and does differ between devices, that's expected. Are you saying that `getFilesDir().exists()` returns false on those devices?

Comment: getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() returns the wrong path, it returns /data/user/0/ but the device has no such directory. It uses data/data/ instead. The way i have in the code above root.exists() returns true.
I want getFilesDir to give me the device specific path, but since it's not working I was trying to work-around by hardcoding the path for those older dir systems (doesn't help since exists returns true).

Comment: The absolute path is expected to be different on different devices. Why are you looking at the absolute path at all?

Comment: I was looking at the absolute path to access my (custom) audio directory, within my apps internal folder.

Comment: Isn't your audio directory always going to be at `new File(getFilesDir(), "audio")` (if your folder is called audio, your code also uses `voice`)? That's what is going to be consistent across every device

Comment: Ok thanks i will try this. (Yes the audio folder is called "voice")

Comment: It worked perfectly with new File(getFilesDir(), "audio") as you suggested @ianhanniballake . Thank you very much. But I still find it odd: as I now play the file, getPath/getAbsolutePath (of the file) gives me `/data/user/0/com.package.name/files/voice/AKInL5ZdvKEFLRxlkzmk.m4a`  and in the Device File Explorer the file is located at  `/data/data/com.package.name/files/voice/AKInL5ZdvKEFLRxlkzmk.m4a`

Comment: `/data/data/` is a symlink to the actual location of `/data/user/0`

Comment: @ianhanniballake I am also facing these types of issues

Could you please explain what is the difference between these two lines of code?

```Code 1:  File(context.filesDir, folderName)```

```Code 2: File("${context.filesDir}/$folderName")```

As per this thread discussion, Code 2 line will not work on some devices, but Code 1 line will always work on any device, why is that?

I am facing this issue in one of my customer devices we do not have access to that exact device so I can not be sure if code 1 will fix this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getFilesDir()` can and does return different absolute paths based on what device you're running on or even what user (for devices that support multiple users) is running your app (that's the `user/0` you're seeing).

As long as you're operating on the directory returned by `getFilesDir()` or subdirectories of it (such as your `new File(getFilesDir(), "voice")` directory), everything will work on every device.

Comment: Encountering a strange issue with getFilesDir(). On a rooted phone if I delete the directory and on next app run calling getFilesDir().mkdir/mkdirs returns false! Any idea why? Also I think this directory automatically gets created on app install or may be first launch?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar - if you look at the [source code for `getFilesDir()`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java;l=689?q=getFilesDir()), you'll note that it tries to automatically create the folder if it doesn't exist, but that the ownership of that folder is more complicated than you might think (the system owns the higher level directories, your app can't write to those directories, which is why you can't create those directories yourself).

Comment: Yeah thanks for pointing out. So you say system owns the directories (getFilesDir) but the docs says `No additional permissions are required for the calling app to read or write files under the returned path`. So what I understood is that the path returned by getFilesDir is only writeable by system but system allow access inside that path for the respective app to perform write operations?

Comment: on root phone. If I delete the directory and on next run when `getFilesDir` is executed why does system fails to create the directory again?

Answer (score 1):

I was confused why `getFilesDir()` creates file in correct directory but not found them when need to delete, `getFilesDir().getPath()` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The [getFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getFilesDir()) method returns an abstract file path that will change based on the storage system.

You can get the /data/data/com.package.name/files pathway by using [getCanonicalFile()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File#getCanonicalFile()). In Kotlin it would look something like this:

```
val filePath = context.filesDir.canonicalFile
```

This gives you the path name specific to the device.